# How do I remove duplicates in json and rearrange the output?

Tags: python, json

I would be greatful if someone would help me! I am trying to create a webscraper for cashpoint.dk which will scrape soccer odds for given urls. 
In my quest I am trying to extract the parsed data to json, I was also thinking about a sqlite3 database, nonetheless, the output with my json extract is really "bugging" me!

How do I format my json code to a format that shows this?

```
{
"bettext": "Hvem vinder kampen?"
     "team1": "Rusland"
     "team2": "Saudi Arabien"

     "tip": "1"
        "odds:" "138"
     "tip": "3"
        "odds: "460"
     "tip": "2"
        "odds: "926"
}
```

**This is the original format just expressing this:**

```
- Russia vs. Saudia Arabia,
- Who will win?,
- 1 (Russia) at odds 1,38,
- 3 (Draw) at odds 4,60, 
- 2 (Saudi Arabia) at odds 9,26

{
          "bettext": "Hvem vinder kampen?",
          "odds": "138",
          "team1": "Rusland",
          "team2": "Saudi Arabien",
          "tip": "1"
}
{
          "bettext": "Hvem vinder kampen?",
          "odds": "138",
          "team1": "Rusland",
          "team2": "Saudi Arabien",
          "tip": "1"
}
{
          "bettext": "Hvem vinder kampen?",
          "odds": "460",
          "team1": "Rusland",
          "team2": "Saudi Arabien",
          "tip": "3"
}
{
          "bettext": "Hvem vinder kampen?",
          "odds": "926",
          "team1": "Rusland",
          "team2": "Saudi Arabien",
          "tip": "2"
}
```

My problem is also that I have exact duplicate objects in the dict.
The code below is the code I use to run it.

```
import demjson
import json
import itertools, json
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/?r=bets/xtra&group=461392&game=312004790"
print(url)

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

class Scraper():

    def __init__(self):

        self.tables = soup.select('table.sportbet_extra_list_table')

        for table in self.tables:
            self.fields = table.select('.sportbet_extra_rate_content')
            for field in self.fields:
                self.js_obj = re.search('{.+}', field['onclick']).group()
                self.bet = demjson.decode(self.js_obj)
                # print(self.bet)
                # print((self.bet['team1'], self.bet['team2'], self.bet['bettext'], self.bet['tiptext'], self.bet['tip']))

                prettyjson = {
                    'tip':      str(self.bet['tip']),
                    'team1':    str(self.bet['team1']),
                    'team2':    str(self.bet['team2']),
                    'bettext':  str(self.bet['bettext']),
                    'odds':     str(self.bet['odd']),

                }

                dumpit = json.dumps(prettyjson, ensure_ascii=True, sort_keys=True, indent=10, separators=(',', ': '))
                print(dumpit)


                with open('result.json', 'a') as outfile:
                    for sprettyjson in self.bet:
                        json.dump(prettyjson, outfile, ensure_ascii=True, sort_keys=True, indent=10, separators=(',', ': '))
                        outfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: jubibanna: Plese [edit] your question and show the input being processed (not how you're obtaining it) and the output desired (or incorrect results you're getting with whatever code you're now using). Doing so _may_ clear up a least some of the confusion about what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my Comment to help clarify what you're asking.

My understanding is that you're trying to reduce multiple JSON objects to a single Object Structure that eliminates duplication of unnecessary data.

The first thing to remember is that JSON objects can have only one instance of a tag at each scope level.

This is not ok:

```
{
  "tag":"value",
  "tag":"value"
}
```

This is ok:

```
{
  "tag":"value",
  "subtag":{ 
             "tag:"value"
           }
}
```

In your case, your "subtag" should be an array of `tips` objects, allowing you to repeat the odds and tip tags as many times as youd like.

Try reworking your code to produce something like this:

```
{
 "bettext": "Hvem vinder kampen?",
 "team1": "Rusland",
 "team2": "Saudi Arabien",
 "tips":[{"tip": "1",
          "odds:" "138"},
         {"tip": "3",
          "odds: "460"},
         {"tip": "2",
          "odds: "926"}]     
}
```